# .NET Core API - Return Image URL from Server and not from local storage

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-apicontroller

In Chrome i get following error:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: C://...
```

Now i want to change the return from the Image in like 'localhost:44346/wwwroot/images/profileimages/img.jpg'

Can you tell my how i can do this?

This is my Controller for the Fileupload:

```
    [HttpPut]
    [Authorize]
    [RequestSizeLimit(1_000_000)]
    [Route("UpdateImage")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateImage([FromForm]ApplicationUserModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(model.id);
            if (user.ProfileImagePath != null)
            {
                var file = new FileInfo(user.ProfileImagePath);
                file.Delete();
            }
            var uniqueFileName = GetUniqueFileName(model.ProfileImage.FileName);
            var uploads = Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Images\\ProfileImages");
            var filePath = Path.Combine(uploads, uniqueFileName);
            await model.ProfileImage.CopyToAsync(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
            user.ProfileImagePath = filePath;

            var result = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

            return Ok(result);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

This is the Controller for getting the User Informations:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
[Route("GetCurrentUser")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCurrentUser()
{
    try
    {
        var userId = User.FindFirst("UserID")?.Value;
        var data = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

        var user = new UserStandardModel
        {
            id = userId,
            LastName = data.LastName,
            FirstName = data.FirstName,
            ProfileImagePath = data.ProfileImagePath
        };


        return Ok(user);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make it simple, filePath = ApplicationHostAddress + $"/wwwroot/images/profileimages/{imageName}". you know your host name, you know the place where your image will be, just concatenate them!!!

Comment: What is the value of : hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i have found a solution for my problem.
When i trigger my GetCurrentUser function than i will check i the FilePath starts with 'C'.
When this is true i will format the filepath with my localhost address. Like Bruno suggested.

But this works only if i have the UseStaticFiles() in my Startup.cs

```
    app.UseStaticFiles();
```

This is not beautiful but it does the work and its only for testing.

```
        var userId = User.FindFirst("UserID")?.Value;
        var data = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

        var user = new UserStandardModel
        {
            id = userId,
            LastName = data.LastName,
            FirstName = data.FirstName,
            ProfileImagePath = data.ProfileImagePath
        };

        if (user.ProfileImagePath.StartsWith('C'))
        {
            var url = "https://localhost:44356/";
            user.ProfileImagePath = user.ProfileImagePath.Remove(0,58);
            user.ProfileImagePath = url + user.ProfileImagePath;
            
        }


        return Ok(user);
```